# OpenCart Product Page shows Front Page

Tags: .htaccess, url, opencart, product

My problem is, on my **OpenCart** website the page which is supposed to display a product displays the home page instead. However this is a step up from what it used to do, it used only give my **404 errors**. Also I am using my own domain but it is in a folder, ie **domain.com/store/**
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can You provide us with the URL? Have You done some changes to the .htaccess while using SEO URLs? I also had some problems while using OpenCart from a root's subdirectory but moved into a subdomain (store.domain.com) and everything is fine since then.

Comment: Turn off SEO urls and check if this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is SEO URL Rewrites, though by default it won't use `common/home` unless you set it to do so. Check the contents of your `.htaccess` match those that OpenCart comes with in the `.htaccess.txt` file and also make sure that your `RewriteBase` is set to `/store/` not `/`

Comment: This was the closest to being correct, I just had to mess with the .htaccess file for it to work. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I think the product is not listed well, there must be some error in the Product page.

Try changing the data of the product, in your DB or by visiting the admin panel of your OC website.